# Unexpected primary-expression before ‘(’ token

Tags: c++, templates

I searched this question, but am unable to figure out how to resolve this:

```
class DtEffect;
template <typename VertexFormat> 
class DtEffectRenderer : public DtFormatRenderer<VertexFormat>
{
public:

template <typename MemberType>
static DtEffect::VertexAttribPtrInfo VertexAttrib(const MemberType VertexFormat::* member)
{
    return DtEffect::VertexAttribPtrInfo(
        reinterpret_cast<const GLvoid*>(offsetof(VertexFormat, *member))
        , DtAttributeType<MemberType>::value
        , DtAttributeType<MemberType>::size);
}

protected:
   DtEffect* myEffect;
};
```

Error messages:

```
../../include/vrvGraphics/DtEffectRenderer.h: In static member function ‘static makVrv::DtEffect::VertexAttribPtrInfo makVrv::DtEffectRenderer<VertexFormat>::VertexAttrib(const MemberType VertexFormat::*)’:
../../include/vrvGraphics/DtEffectRenderer.h:115: error: expected primary-expression before ‘(’ token
../../include/vrvGraphics/DtEffectRenderer.h:116: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘*’ token
../../include/vrvGraphics/DtEffectRenderer.h:116: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `VertexFormat::*`?

Comment: Its usage is like so:

      myEffect->setVertexAttribPointers( sizeof(DtLineVertex),
         VertexAttrib(&DtLineVertex::position),
         VertexAttrib(&DtLineVertex::color),
         VertexAttrib(&DtLineVertex::offset),
         VertexAttrib(&DtLineVertex::directionAndLength) );

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: post more code please. if member is supposed to be a function pointer than lookup how to phrase a proper function pointer type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to use [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) macro to get an offset to a member identified through a pointer-to-member:

```
offsetof(VertexFormat, *member)
```

This is not going to work, because the second parameter of the `offsetof` macro must be member's name, not any kind of an expression that could be used to access the member. Compile error is decidedly cryptic, but there is little the compiler could do, because `offsetof` is a macro.

See [0xbadf00d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547231/0xbadf00d)'s answer to this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5617632/335858) for information on finding member offset using pointer-to-member. His approach closely replicates the inner workings of the `offsetof` macro, but he uses a pointer to member instead of member's name.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a missing '(' after VertexAttribPtrInfo. I added it back in below, try that to see if it works.

```
template <typename MemberType>
static DtEffect::VertexAttribPtrInfo VertexAttrib(const MemberType VertexFormat::* member)
{
return DtEffect::VertexAttribPtrInfo((
    reinterpret_cast<const GLvoid*>(offsetof(VertexFormat, *member))
    , DtAttributeType<MemberType>::value
    , DtAttributeType<MemberType>::size);
}
```

Comment: That doesnt work. I don't think I am missing a (. It compiles on Windows fine, but not on gcc

Comment: Whoah, messed that up, my mistake.